# Rotate OnlineResource in SLD for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, xml

How can I rotate an OnlineResource (Raster image fill that can't be auto-generated by QGIS)?
I tried: [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224908/rotation-in-geoserver-sld) and also just to write a "Rotate" tag everywhere, it didn't do the job.

Edit: I'm using GeoServer 2.11.2, and this is the sld I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>fill</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>fill test</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>test</Name>
          <Title>test</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>CODE</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>1250</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
              <Fill>
               <GraphicFill>
                 <Graphic>
                   <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource
                       xlink:type="simple"
                       xlink:href="1250b.png" />
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                   </ExternalGraphic>
                 <Size>100</Size>
                 <Rotation>45</Rotation>
                 </Graphic>
               </GraphicFill>
             </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Please share the full SLD you're using and also the GeoServer version.

Comment: The tag should be Rotation

Comment: edit has been done